# Magento 2: Why No LoginController on `customer/account/login`

Tags: configuration, controllers, magento2, routing

If I understand my Magento 2 routing -- the URL `customer/account/login` has a front name of `customer`.  This means it's "claimed" by the `Magento_Customer` module.

```
#File: app/code/Magento/Customer/etc/frontend/routes.xml
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="customer" frontName="customer">
            <module name="Magento_Customer" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Which in turn, means the `account/login` portion of the URL will translate into the following controller file.

```
app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/Login.php
```

However -- this doesn't appear to be what's happening in practice.  If I drop in some `var_dump` exit debugging

```
#File: app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/Login.php 
public function execute()
{
    var_dump(__METHOD__);
    exit;    
    //...
}
```

The page execution doesn't halt.  Also, if I drop in a

```
print_r(get_included_files());
```

at the end of `index.php`, there's no `Login.php` listed.  This is true for both a cached page hit, and a complete cache rebuild.

- Why doesn't `customer/account/login` router through `app/code/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/Login.php`
- Where does it route through?
- If my questions don't make sense, what core piece of information am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tracked this one down myself -- despite my clearing the cache from the command line

```
$ php bin/magento cache:clean
Cleaned cache types:
config
layout
block_html
collections
db_ddl
eav
full_page
translate
config_integration
config_integration_api
config_webservice
```

Magento wasn't actually clearing the cached content in

```
var/page_cache/*
```

A manual clearing of those files appears to have fixed things, and the correct controller showed up.

Comment: Very valuable to know that cache:clean (which supposedly now does --all by default?) doesn't clear page_cache! Hopefully that will be fixed soon, though.

Comment: @JaredTyler I think it does clear those caches, but wasn't on my system due to a permissions error.